# paypal ipn listener errors

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm implementing an IPN listener for Paypal Adaptive Payments, I downloaded the sample code from here:

https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/IT/it_IT/files/developer/IPN_PHP_41.txt

Then I made a transaction (with sandbox) but I think the sample is wrong because the code returns some errors in my error_log file:

```
[16-Jun-2013 16:11:34 UTC] PHP Warning:  stripslashes() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/actions/IPNListener.php on line 7
[16-Jun-2013 16:11:34 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: header in /var/www/actions/IPNListener.php on line 12
[16-Jun-2013 16:11:34 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: item_name in /var/www/actions/IPNListener.php on line 18
```

The Undefined index is not only "item_name" but ALL INDEXES!!!!!

The transaction works correctly and the IPN is called by paypal automatically after the transaction...but the paypal sample code does not work at all! Do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<?php
//Build the data to post back to Paypal
$postback = 'cmd=_notify-validate'; 

// go through each of the posted vars and add them to the postback variable
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
   $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
   $postback .= "&$key=$value";
}

// build the header string to post back to PayPal system to validate
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($postback) . "\r\n\r\n";

// Send to paypal or the sandbox depending on whether you're live or developing
// comment out one of the following lines
//$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);//open the connection
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
// or use port 443 for an SSL connection
//$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

    if (!$fp) 
    {
        // HTTP ERROR Failed to connect
        //error handling
    }
    else // if we've connected OK
    {
        fputs ($fp, $header . $postback);//post the data back
        while (!feof($fp)) 
        {
            $response = fgets ($fp, 1024);

            if (strcmp ($response, "VERIFIED") == 0) //It's verified
            {
                //do something
            }
            else if (strcmp ($response, "INVALID") == 0) 
            { 
                //the Paypal response is INVALID, not VERIFIED
                // This implies something is wrong
            }
        } //end of while
        fclose ($fp);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, but it returns the same errors: [16-Jun-2013 16:37:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  stripslashes() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/actions/IPNListener.php on line 7
[16-Jun-2013 16:37:27 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: header in /var/www/actions/IPNListener.php on line 25

Comment: Thank you! The header now is ok but there is still left an error: [16-Jun-2013 18:12:45 UTC] PHP Warning:  stripslashes() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/actions/IPNListener.php on line 7

Comment: That is PHP warning it is not an error. You can disable PHP warnings in `php.ini` file or write this at the top of the page `error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);`

Comment: ok but the Paypal response is INVALID, that's the real problem!

Comment: Solved! I found the working code on paypal SDK, but thank you again! :)